# (EXCEL-VBA) Trying to pass a date as criteria in a MedianIFS UDF, but only the month is parsed (via MID function) for the criteria threshold

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, date-format

I am using a MEDIANIFS UDF (by Dan Wagner) to filter radiation badge readings by User name and date (<= user specified date and > date 12 months prior). The date is passed to the UDF by a variable in my own subroutine, but when the varThreshold variable is defined, its only showing up as the month (IE: instead of 7/28/2018, varThreshold = 7). This makes the logic arguments that follows come back as false. The varThreshold is defined by data parsed by the Mid function. It appears to stop parsing the string once it hits the "/" delimiter. Code samples below.

My Subroutine snippet that invokes the MEDIANIFS UDF:

```
'-------------Calculate current and past 12 month dates and assign to variables
    mth = Month(DateValue("01 " & Range("D2") & " 2019"))
    yr = Range("E2")
    currDate = DateSerial(yr, mth, 28)
    pastDate1 = DateAdd("M", -12, currDate)
    pastDate = DateAdd("D", -27, pastDate1)
'-------------Loop to apply past 12 month calculation to each individual Doctor
For i = mdX To mdY
    EPmdNme = Range("A" & i)
    Range("B" & i) = MEDIANIFS(LdeRng, NameRng, EPmdNme, DateRng, "<=" & currDate, DateRng, ">" & pastDate)
    Range("B" & i).NumberFormat = "0.0"
Next I
```

Here currDate = 7/28/18

The Relevant Part of the MEDIANIFS UDF:

```
        'Loop through all the range / criteria pairs
    For lngCriteriaIdx = LBound(range_and_criteria_pairs) To UBound(range_and_criteria_pairs) Step 2
        'Identify the threshold and the operator for use in the criteria phase
        Select Case Left(range_and_criteria_pairs(lngCriteriaIdx + 1), 2)
            Case Is = "<="
                strOperator = "<="
                varThreshold = Val(Mid(range_and_criteria_pairs(lngCriteriaIdx + 1), 3))
            Case Is = ">="
                strOperator = ">="
                varThreshold = Val(Mid(range_and_criteria_pairs(lngCriteriaIdx + 1), 3))
```

This makes varThreshold = 7

Later in the MEDIANIFS UDF the varThreshold gets compared to the "Data" variable. In this instance, Data = #1/1/18#:

```
            'Criteria phase: check each cell in the passed-in ParamArray against the threshold
        With range_and_criteria_pairs(lngCriteriaIdx)

            Data = .Cells(lngMedianRowIdx, 1).Value
            If VarType(Data) = 7 Then
                Data = CDate(.Cells(lngMedianRowIdx, 1).Value)
            ElseIf VarType(Data) = 8 Then
                Data = UCase(.Cells(lngMedianRowIdx, 1).Value)
            Else
                Data = .Cells(lngMedianRowIdx, 1).Value
            End If

                'Check the operator (">=", "<=", "<", ">", "<>", and "=") against the cell
            Select Case strOperator
                Case Is = "<=" '<~ check if cell is less than or equal to the threshold
                    If Data <= varThreshold Then
                        blnAllMatched = True
                    Else
                        blnAllMatched = False
                    End If
```

Obviously, this comes back as false and negates the entire UDF.

How can I get the varThreshold to equal currDate so varThreshold = 7/28/18 so that Data <= varThreshold (#1/1/18# <= 7/28/18) so I get a "true" result?

The varThreshold is also used for filtering the name so it has to be defined as variant.

Comment: I removed the Val() function preceding the Mid() function and that gave me the full date. Should solve the issue for now. I am still curious if it still allows for a multitude of variable types to still be logically compared reliably. Im still new to all of this so if you have any extra thoughts, tips, concerns let me know.

Comment: Have a look at [DatePart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datepart-function?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1012951)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue). It will make your date parsing so much cleaner and safer.